# Unable to install mimix package on my windows laptop

Tags: r, github, installation, remotes

I am trying to install mimix package by simply typing:

```
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("UCL/mimix")
```

I got this instruction from https://rdrr.io/github/UCL/mimix/.

My problem is I get this error message:

```
Error in parse(outFile) :C:/Users/WC/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpsjKHP6/R.INSTALL4258415545b8/RefBasedMI/R/Runmimix.R:768:7
unexpected 'else'
767:         #else if(!is.null(methodindiv[1]))
768:     } else
```

Comment: That file in that package is broken, it is not complete code.

Comment: The last version of MImix pushed to CRAN appears to be in [2012](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/MImix/), _suggesting_ possible unsupported and broken code. When I go to `github.com/UCL/mimix`, I am redirected to `github.com/UCL/RefbasedMI`, which is not on CRAN yet. I don't know what you need to be doing nor what is suggesting that `mimix` is the package you need, but you may need to look elsewhere (or press "I believe", download the `.tar.gz` file, and attempt to install it _anyway_ ... **not recommended**).

Comment: Thank you for this. I actually want to conduct multiple imputation for the outcome longitudinal variable because some participants in a trial did not finish their treatment. I don't know if you have suggestions.

Comment: I've heard a lot of chatter about the [`mice`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/index.html) package.